# ¿Cómo hago consultas o condiciones if con nombres de variables concatenadas (variable1, variable2) en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, condiciones, script

Tengo una variable llamada `respuesta` que es la que responde mi usuario a un número de preguntas.

Para ello inicialicé la variable `cont=1`, ya que tengo otra variable de la cantidad de preguntas `cantpreguntas` que debe responder el usuario... Mi cuestión es, ¿Cómo tengo variables de las respuestas correctas?

Ejemplo, `correcta1` de la `pregunta1`:

```js
if (cont < cantpreguntas) {
    if (respuesta==correcta1) {
        // Realizar acción de respuesta correcta
        cont++;
   }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo cambiar dinámicamente o concatenando el nombre de la variable en mi consulta `if`, que el el `if (respuesta==correcta1)` cuando es `cont=2`, que la consulta sea `if (respuesta==correcta2)`?

¿Es posible hacer eso? En *PHP* se que se puede con `${'correcta1'.$cont}`, pero en *JavaScript* no sé cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo visto necesitas iterar sobre n cantidad de respuestas correctas, entonces deberías almacenar los valores de cada variable 'correcta' en un Array primeramente:

```
   let correctas = ['correcta', 'Sócrates', 0] 
        //el valor que contenga cada variable 'correcta' debería ingresarse al Array
```

De esta manera tienes indexados los valores. Y luego deberías iterar sobre este Array:

```
correctas.for(let i = 0; i < correctas.length; i++;) {
    if(respuesta == correctas[i]) {
           // Lo que tengas que hacer
        }    
    }
```

Espero haberte sido útil